# Update multiple entities via RequestFactory

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I have a GWT applications that contains Products and Experts, and one Product can have multiple Experts (OneToMany relationship). I have some trouble mixing and combining the requests using two entities that are related:

The ProductProxy looks like this:

```
@ProxyFor(myapplication.server.domain.Product.class)
public interface ProductProxy extends EntityProxy {

    Long getId();

    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);

    [...]

    EntityProxyId<ProductProxy> stableId();

    Set<ExpertProxy> getExperts();
}
```

I have a Dialog that can edit the Product, so it does a:

```
ProductProxy selectedProduct; // This comes from a function that delivered all products
productRequest = MyAplication.getRequestFactory().productRequest();
this.product = productRequest.edit(selectedProduct);
```

When editing the product, you can also add experts to this product:

```
@ProxyFor(myapplication.server.domain.Expert.class)

public interface ExpertProxy extends EntityProxy {
    public Long getId();
    public void setId(Long id);

    public ProductProxy getProduct();
    public void setProduct(ProductProxy product);
    [...]
}
```

I have a separate DialogBox that appears for it. Inside this dialog box, I try to create an expert with the product that is edited before passed on as parameter:

```
expertRequest = MyApplication.getRequestFactory().expertRequest();
ExpertProxy expert = expertRequest.create(ExpertProxy.class);
expert.setProduct(product); // product comes from the productRequest code
```

If I try this out, I get an error when doing the **setProduct**, because the request from productRequest is mixed with a request from expertRequest.

What's the best way to fix this? Can I add an expert via the original productRequest? Should I get the Id from the product and only use this in my Expert Request? Or should I add specific Server functions to add an expert to a product? Or are there better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the same `RequestContext` instance for all your edits/creates.

Each `RequestContext` accumulates operations (new proxies and setters called on proxies) and invocations (service method calls) to be *replayed* on the server. This is all sent as a batch when you `fire()`. So your `ExpoertProxy` must be created from the same `RequestContext` as the `ProductProxy` you add it to.

Comment: So should I save the result from MyAplication.getRequestFactory() and store it to generate both the productRequest() and expertRequest() ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice you had two `RequestContext` interfaces. In that case, then [`append()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/RequestContext.html#append%28T%29) the `expertRequest()` to the existing `productRequest()` before you `create()` the `ExpertProxy`. You can append that way as many `expoertRequest()` instances as needed, so you don't have to keep a reference on the `expertRequest()`. BTW, your `RequestFactory` instance should probably be a singleton.

Comment: Oh, actually, no; you don't call any service method on the `expertRequest()`, so you don't need it: simply `create(ExpertProxy.class)` on the `productRequest()` of your _main screen_.

Comment: merci beaucoup! The comment on using create(ExpertProxy.class) on the original productRequest() looked illogical at first, but is exactly what I needed. So this comment is the real answer.